# SQL pivot datewise amount for receipts based on receipt type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

i am looking for help in creating pivot, which will show datewise amount for receipts based on receipt type.

Sample data:

```
receipt_no  Receipt receipt_date    receipt_amount
0115D171073-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  338.00
0115D171074-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  185.00
0115D171075-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  187.00
0115D171076-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  250.00
0115D171077-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  25.00
0115D171078-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  6.50
0115D171079-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  35.00
0115D171080-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  210.00
0115D171081-CA  Cash Receipt    04/01/2015  25.00
0115D171082-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  209.00
0115D171083-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  280.00
0115D171084-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  25.00
0115D171085-CH  Cheque Receipt  27/12/2014  365.60
0115D171086-CH  Cheque Receipt  27/12/2014  365.60
0115D171087-CC  CreditCard Receipt  04/01/2015  372.50
```

result expected as

```
Date      cash receipt       creditcard receipt      cheque receipt
27/12/2015     xxxxx.xx       xxxxx.xx               xxxx.xx
04/01/2015     xxxxx.xx       xxxxx.xx               xxxx.xx
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN receipt_no like '%CA%' THEN 'Cash Receipt'
WHEN receipt_no like '%CC%' THEN 'CreditCard Receipt'
WHEN receipt_no like '%CH%' THEN 'Cheque Receipt'
END AS Receipt, receipt_date, receipt_amount
FROM rpt_receipt_hdr
) Receipt
PIVOT
(
    SUM(receipt_amount)
    FOR receipt_date in (receipt_date)
)PIV
```

please help me create date wise pivot

Answer (score 2):

you don't need `PIVOT`, a simple `GROUP BY` with `CASE` will also do. Something like this.

```
SELECT 
receipt_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN receipt_no like '%CA%' THEN receipt_amount END) [Cash Receipt],
SUM(CASE WHEN receipt_no like '%CC%' THEN receipt_amount END) [CreditCard Receipt],
SUM(CASE WHEN receipt_no like '%CH%' THEN receipt_amount END)  [Cheque Receipt]
FROM rpt_receipt_hdr
GROUP BY receipt_date
```

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out..

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN receipt_no like '%CA%' THEN 'Cash Receipt'
WHEN receipt_no like '%CC%' THEN 'CreditCard Receipt'
WHEN receipt_no like '%CH%' THEN 'Cheque Receipt'
END AS [Receipt], receipt_date, receipt_amount
FROM rpt_receipt_hdr
) Receipt
PIVOT
(
    SUM(receipt_amount)
    FOR [Receipt] in ([Cash Receipt],[CreditCard Receipt],[Cheque Receipt])
)PIV
```

this works fine...

Comment: You can achieve the same without using a `PIVOT` and with just a `GROUP BY`. Check my answer.